# Should I send POST data cross domains?

Tags: php, html, cross-domain

What is the best practice as such? I have an iframe with a form and when it submits it updates the parent page. Currently it sends the form contents via GET so the parent page url reflects this. I can do the same via POST, but am wondering if this is frowned upon and if sometimes this is blocked/ unuseable.

Any help and advice is welcomed

Comment: cross domain form submission has no security restrictions, as long as it's not javascript doing an ajax request. a full-blown `<form>` can submit anywhere it wants to.

Comment: So the receiving page would never block / could block? a cross domain post request?

Comment: that's up to the receiving page. e.g. it may have antispam measures that your submission doesn't contain, it may check referers, etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no problems caused by using POST across domains (at least none that you wouldn't get from using POST on the same domain or GET on a different domain).

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem submitting a form to a different domain, unless via javascript.

One concern to keep in mind is validations. You would want to take care on what happens when the form has errors, as you wouldn't want them to loose the information they've typed in if they missed something like 'name'. The server should be the final line of defense for validations, but you'll want to make sure that the client side validations for your form match those of the server and appropriately notify the user of their (or the server's) mistake.

The other thing that could potentially block a form from submitting over post would be a form that requires an authentication token. These are used by many different frameworks to prevent CSRF (Cross-site request forgery) attacks and ensures that the form was submitted from the same website domain.